# How to fix: code not running on certain frames

Tags: gml

I have been trying to make my character shoot a projectile on a particular frame of animation. However, sometimes it works and other times it just ignores creating the projectile.

I've tried using alarms instead of checking for the image index but I can't get the timer low enough to get the perfect timing.

I think it may be a problem with the image speed being 0.2 instead of 1.

I'm using a state machine to make it switch between moving and shooting, but I checked and it isn't a problem with state switching over as it changes when I want it to.

Here is relevant code from the shooting state:

```
if image_index == 2 {
   instance_create(x+20*image_xscale,y,obj_projectile);
}
```

Here is the code that changes the tank over to the shooting state from the main state:

```
if key_shoot{
   state = states.shoot;
   image_speed = 0.2;
   sprite_index = spr_tankShoot;
}
```

There is also an animation end event in the object with the following code:

```
if sprite_index == spr_tankShoot{
   state = states.normal;
}
```

If anyone can see something wrong with the code and/or know what might be going wrong with this, it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think it may be a problem with the image speed being 0.2 instead of 1.

This is possible - if your animations have different speeds and you don't tend to reset image_index on animation start, you may end up with varying starting indexes (suppose, 0.1) that would not fall right on 2.0 when adding 0.2 to them. Checking that a frame is precisely a number is a not-as-good practice in general though.

You could store image_index at the end of the frame for future reference,

```
image_index_previous = image_index;
```

and then check that image_index stepped over 2 since the last frame:

```
if image_index_previous < 2 && image_index >= 2 {
   instance_create(x+20*image_xscale,y,obj_projectile);
}
```